# Firebase How to retrieve a collection of documents, along with a child collection for each document in one go?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am using Angular and Firestore to contain a set of user "projects", each of which may have multiple "budgets" associated with that project

What I want is a list of projects, with the list of budgets for each project

What I want to see on the page

```
Project A
      budget 1 
      budget 2
   Project B
     budget c 
     budget d
     budget e
   Project C
     ...
```

Documents are stuctured with each project having its own a collection of budgets.

I can think of a variety of probably inefficient ways to do this, reading the list of projects first, and the iterating the projects to retrieve each ones budget collection, but somehow it seems like I ought to be able to do this in one go.

What is the usual way to do this, if its possible??
.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  Queries in Firestore are shallow - you can only read documents from a single collection (or [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)) at once, neither of which is the case here.  You will have to make multiple queries if your documents are distributed multiple collections.

If you must be able to do this in one query, all the documents should be in the same collection, or in subcollections all with the same string ID.